VS Code Python unittest not finding tests to run
VS Code latest version.
I have a file test_whatever.py
import unittest   
class Test_TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_whatever(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

if __name__= '__main__':
    unittest.main()

In Explorer if I right-click this file and select "Run Tests" it finds the test and runs it.
However, if I modify the file as follows :
import unittest   
import binarySearch

class Test_TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_whatever(self):
        self.assertEqual(binarySearch.binarySearch(), 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Then VS Code reports that "No tests found in the selected file or folder."
By experimentation I found that just the presence of import binarySearch will cause it to no longer be able to find the test.
import unittest   
import binarySearch

class Test_TestWhatever(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_whatever(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Is there a certain folder/file structure that I need to follow ?
Here's my layout :
.\src\binarySearch.py 
.\test\test_whatever.py

Here is my settings.json
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./test",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./src"
    ]
}


There are two common styles of Python project layout, src layout and flat layout and you appear to have gone for "src layout". One of the important behaviour differences is that the "src layout" helps prevent accidental usage of the in-development copy of the code.
The "src layout" helps enforce that an editable installation is only able to import files that were meant to be importable.
This is because the "src" directory is not on the module search path
You could switch your project to a "flat layout" or you could create a pyproject.toml file so that you can do an "editable install".
A simple example of a pyproject.toml file in the root of your project might look like:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_package"
version = "0.1.0"

And then you can do an editable install into your venv e.g.
pip install --editable .

You will then see your project has been installed with pip list. For example, after I did it looked like:
$ pip list
Package    Version Editable project location
---------- ------- --------------------------------------------
my_package 0.1.0   /home/user/projectRoot
pip        24.2
setuptools 74.0.0

And the VSCode tests will run as expected.
